# Adding padding to fa-fw Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

like title says I'm trying to add padding arround  font Awsome icon with class fa-fw -comming here from android and java so am a bit confused and trying to get a grasp of css at the moent but that part I just can't figure out:S here is the code:

```
<div class="mainpage">
  main-page works!
 <i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.fa-fw {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

and the result I'm getting:
[image: pic]

edit: 
resst of the code :

```
<div class="main-wrapper" style="background: green">
  <app-top-bar (onToggleEmiter)="isMenuClosed =$event"></app-top-bar>
  <div class="wrapper-sub" [ngClass]="{extendedBar:sidebarIsExpended === true}">
    <div class="row container-fluid">
      <div *ngIf="(isMenuClosed)===true; else noth" class="weee">
        <app-side-bar class="hidde"></app-side-bar>
      </div>
      <ng-template #noth>
        <app-side-bar class="nothidde"></app-side-bar>
      </ng-template>
      <app-main-page></app-main-page>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the result you want ?

Comment: What else do you have on that page? I tried with just your example and the credit card is centered in the yellow square on mine.

Comment: @bhansa I want that yellow background to be 10px arounf icon

Comment: @Reginol_Blindhop here is the code(look 'edit' in the question)

Comment: Check the below example, it gives the proper padding with background, you need to check what else is on page and width of your element.

Answer (score 1):

You example works fine, here you have the `10px` padding with yellow background.

```css
.fa-fw{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="mainpage">
  main-page works!
  <i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: yeap, why the h**l it's doesn't work for me:/- can it be that it is a child of 'container-fluid' bootstrap class U think...?:S

Comment: Check your browser for other styles applied on the same element and try to figure out, there might be something overriding these styles.

Comment: ty for suggestion Sir -will keep on fighting with that(y)

Comment: I tryed everyhing and what I noticed is that width of my icon is "0" when in your exemple width has a  normal value (that is  greater than 0) - what I'm guessing is that class fa-fw(that comes in font-awsome)  give in my situation a value 0 when in your it is ignored and handled it as it is your custome class (because when I take out fa-fw class from the i-element it works for me as well -problem is that I need that class)

Comment: @pb4now so you are saying it's not working with the fontawesome class, it's giving the width *0*.

Comment: yeap - I acctuelly made it work by overiding width and height of fa-fw class to 50px -still a bit confused why it doesn't work with padding - but it works now anyway:)- ty for your help  and time @bhansa(y)